# UIScrollView scroll viewcontrollers broken autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have 2 view controllers which works properly good when I presentViewController them. Now, I've created a ViewController with a `UIScrollView` to scroll the ViewContoller as 'Scroll UIviewContoller Apple's Example' When I enter in `HomesViewController` (the controller which the UIScrollView that control the others UIViewController) the layout is total broken, size and positions. When I go out to another page and back again to `HomesViewController`, the layout is working, respecting the autolayout constraints. I have already tried to implement -`(void)didAutoLayout` and reload InputViews, but it doesn't work. I will not paste my code, because the ScrolLView works, when I go out from the page and back again...then I think its a problem with refreshing layout...

Comment: You should be using a UIPageViewController which is literally built to create this type of layout.

Comment: @DBoyer you are right! I used UIPageViewController and it works! Please, make an Answer and I mark as correct answer

Comment: Glad to hear that! I'll create an answer right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `UIPageViewController` it is an excellent way to create a paged "scrollView" of view controllers. This is often used for things like app tutorials.

Apple has already done the work for you :)